# Gelfand-Naimark-Segal construction confused

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I think I understand this some what, but still kinda confused. Let $A$ be a $^*$-algebra and $\varphi$ be a functional on $A$. My professor defined positive functional as $\varphi(x^*x) \geq 0$. From this functional we can define a function $$\langle x, y \rangle_\varphi = \varphi(y^*x)$$I know that I can show that this is a semi-inner product. Then I can define $\mathcal{N}_\varphi := \{x \in A: \langle x, x \rangle_\varphi = 0\}$. I can show that this is a left ideal for our algebra $A$. Then, they induce an inner product on $A/\mathcal{N}_\varphi$. Would this inner product be $\langle x + \mathcal{N}_\varphi, y + \mathcal{N}_\varphi \rangle := \langle x, y \rangle_\varphi$? Also, I never understood what they mean by the completion? I obviously know that a metric space that is complete means that every cauchy sequence converges. I know that if $A/\mathcal{N}_\varphi$ is complete under our innerproduct norm, then it's a Hilbert space. However, I know that not all the time $A/\mathcal{N}_\varphi$ may not be complete. Sorry if this is obvious since I feel that I understand most of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you say is fine. And yes, the inner product in the quotient is defined by taking the inner product of two representatives.

A metric space will usually not be complete, but [it can be completed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space#Completion).

Since the metric you are using is induced by the inner product, it is easy to show that the inner product is bi-continuous and hence it extends to the completion. Now you have a complete inner product space, hence a Hilbert space.